# Playing alarm in iphone with EKEvent

Tags: ios, alarm, ekevent

I am working on application which stores event using `EKEvent` class and I want my application to fire alarm when that event occurs. I don't know how to play alarm in iPhone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can manipulate this code to play alarm using EKEvent..

```
NSMutableArray *myAlarmsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

EKAlarm *alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600]; // 1 Hour
EKAlarm *alarm2 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-86400]; // 1 Day

[myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm1];
[myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm2];

event.alarms = myAlarmsArray;
[myAlarmsArray release];
```

I think [this](http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-event-kit-framework/) small blog post will be useful to you...Hope this helps...cheers

Comment: Thanks for code, i use that but how can i use that code if i have fixed data and time for alarm to ring at that time? i.e i want alarm to ring for "05/03/2011 05:03:00 PM" how can i use for that?

Comment: Sorry for delay..But I think you can use  (EKAlarm *)alarmWithAbsoluteDate:(NSDate *)date

Comment: Can we set custom sound in EKAlarm

Comment: @iCoder86 u can use alarm.absoluteDate=date; to ring for "05/03/2011 05:03:00 PM"